# twitter integration jquery mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, twitter

I am developing application using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap and this application i want to integrate twitter.
i try this.

```
<script type="https://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/'user'.json?count=30&callback=listTweets" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT IS:

```
function listTweets(data){
console.log(data);
var output = '<ul data-role="listview">';

$.each(data, function(key, val){
   var text = data[key].text;
   var thumbnail = data[key].user.profile_image_url;
   var name = data[key].user.name;

   output += '<li>';
   output += '<img src="' +thumbnail+ '" alt="Photo Of ' +name+  '">';
   output += '<div>' +text+ '</div>';
   output += '</li>';
   });
   output += '</ul>';
   $('#tweetlist').html(output);
}
```

html is:

```
<div data-role="page" id="tweets">
<div data-role="content" id="tweetlist">
</div>
</div>
```

it give me blank screen and when I inspect element it give me:

Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi)

Any suggestion

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `refresh` call as specified here : http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh

```
$("#tweetlist").listview('refresh');
```

should works.

**EDIT**

My apologies. I didn't read your code carefully. The main problem is your `$.each` loop. You close the `ul`tag and you display the result **before** the end of the loop (JS is functionnal don't you remember?) Try this:

```
function listTweets(data){
    console.log(data);
    var output = '<ul data-role="listview">';
    var text, thumbnail, name;

    // Use a loop instead a $.each
    for(var i=0, _len=data.length; i < length; i++) {
       text = data[i].text;
       thumbnail = data[i].user.profile_image_url;
       name = data[i].user.name;

       output += '<li>';
       output += '<img src="' +thumbnail+ '" alt="Photo Of ' +name+  '">';
       output += '<div>' +text+ '</div>';
       output += '</li>';
    }
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#tweetlist').html(output);
    $("#tweetlist").listview('refresh'); // In case of
}
```

Comment: Did you control you data? Did you try in a desktop browser? Did you output with `console.log(output)`? Finding a bug with Cordova could be sometimes very hard.

Comment: yes i try in a desktop browser and it show me blank scrren

Comment: Just before the end of your routine, add `console.log(output)` and then reload. Watch the console output (F12 on PC). If it don't display anything, you got you error. You can add as much as `console.log` as you want to watch what appends in your code.

Comment: Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) 
i try what you told me and it gives me this.